# What are the main purposes for vaadin router templates

Tags: vaadin-flow

Vaadin URL route templates marked sometimes as cool new feature.
I've just started with Vaadin, knowing the principle of routes, but what is the main purpose for those route templates ?

kind regard
Dominik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route templates give more flexibility for parameter position and requirements over the basic `HasUrlParameter<T>` that only handles parameters at the end of the route.

In particular, it allows you to use multiple parameters for the same route or to have URL structures where the parameter is not at the end, e.g `products/123/edit` where `123` is the parameter that identifies a product id.

For samples and information see https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/routing/templates